# Execution context of console.log

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am playing with the `console.log`. I understand that the `log` has to be executed in the context of `console`. We can either do `console.log('message')` or `console.log.call(console, 'message')`.

I have two code snippets here:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log);   // doesn't work!!!
```

The one that works goes:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('data', console.log);  // works!!!
});
```

Anybody familiar with what is happening behind the scenes? How the functions are getting called in these two scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first example, like you pointed out, is that `log` doesn't work outside the context (`this`) being set to `console`.

I'm not sure why the 2nd one works.  As far as I can tell from skimming the source, this is the function that executes your callback: [EventEmitter:77](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1fa0cb83e323db6d077e0e9970f3776eb5805140/lib/events.js#L77).  It's setting `this` to the EventEmitter itself, which doesn't have the `_stdout` property `log` is looking for: [Console:36](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1fa0cb83e323db6d077e0e9970f3776eb5805140/lib/console.js#L36).  Debugging and stepping into `on` might answer your question, though.

Here are some examples of ways to fix this for anyone curious:
simplest (ES5):

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log.bind(log));
```

same, but using ES2016 syntax (available if you're using Babel stage 0):

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(::console.log);
```

helper function (ES5):

```
function logger() {
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}

[1, 2, 3].forEach(logger);
```

helper function (ES2015):

```
function logger(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
}

[1, 2, 3].forEach(logger);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and detailed answer. Just figured that out. It's just an implementation issue. The nodejs (at least v0.12.7) simply allow 'null' as the thisArg for `console.log`.  We can do `console.log.call(null, 'message')` or `var log = console.log; log('message')` in node environment.